# Adding Class Structure to Basic Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object

this is pretty crazy, and I feel really stupid asking this. But I have a basic code in Ruby and it's comprised of

1. user input assigned to value
2. input extracted to array by line
3. iterations over each line extracting specific text and specific numbers
4. if /else statements

> if text includes specific words then you apply math
>   if text includes specific words you don't apply math
>
> i also have a running total that i assign outside the loop and add to inside the loop
>
> this all works fine, but the project requires class structure, how do i take a code basically 
>   simple with if else statements basic loop (`for each do |x|`) and basic `variable = true`, or `variable = input * 52/ 300`

where do i start making this into class-based structure with OOP?

Comment: Does the project have any guidelines on how you should use classes? You could make a class (for instance) to hold the code that processes each line. A variable to hold the input and a method to iterate over each line.

Comment: Not really it just says show knowledge of object oriented programming and right now i have no classes in my script

Comment: production-quality, able to maintain/build on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a basic outline to get your started, but I won't do your work for you.  :)

**First:** define a class to hold your input.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
    ...put your initialization code here, this gets run when you call MyClass.new()
  end
  attr_accessor :data 
  ...
end
```

**Second:** define a "container" class to hold multiple instances of class.

```
class MyContainer
  def initialize(record)
    @records << record
  end
  ...
end
```

**Third:** for each line received, create a new instance of your class

```
mydata = MyClass.new(input)
```

**Forth:** store the new instance in your container class.

```
MyContainer.new(mydata)
```

Now, you can do things like create an `add` method in MyContainer which will iterate though all the classes it's holding in @records and produce a sum.

Comment: thanks so much! I'm just starting with ruby, so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Sure thing, be sure to mark this as answered if you don't mind.